# Ubuntu 23.04 : Mutter 44.3-0ubuntu1 + "any" Nvidia drivers crashes at boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, crash, 23.04, mutter

Ubuntu 23.04 fresh install works on my laptop (DELL precision 7550 / Quatro T2000 Mobile). After a fresh install, if I make all currently available updates, the PC crashes during next boot, in graphic mode (it shows the gray screen with the sad computer icon). This is before the login screen, so I cannot select Xorg or Wayland.

I empirically understood it comes from Mutter, as if I install all updates but not Mutter, still from  23.04 fresh install, the PC boots. I work with Wayland at this time.

Also, if I activate the XOrg driver, the PC boots, I still use Wayland. Activating any available Nvidia driver (535, 525, 470) makes the PC crash at boot again.

Is there a workaround somewhere, or should I notice this bug somewhere ?

Best regards,
Mikhaël